# Aggregate data.frame rows using data table with multiple collapse functions

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate

I have a large `data.frame` of this example structure:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c("a","b","c"),4), sex = rep(c("M","F"),6), score = 1:12)
```

I'd like to efficiently aggregate it by the `id` column and comma separated paste the unique `sex` values and keep the maximum `score` value.

How can I modify this `data.table` function to achieve that:

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ",")), by = list(id)]
```

Comment: `df[, .(unique_sex = toString(unique(sex)), score_max = max(score)), by = id]`?

Comment: Why the use od .SD here? In you real data , Do you have others columns?

Comment: @user1701545, if this answers your question, please feel free to post an answer yourself. agstudy's question is very valid

Comment: agstudy, I'm using SD since that's what I know to be more efficient than the dplyr option. Other than that there's no particular reason. Do you have a better solution than SD?

Comment: Why start with a `data.frame`? Just do `DT <- data.table(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use `strsplit`? How about keeping the `sex` values as a `list`? Like so:

```
df[ , .(list(sex), max(score)), by = id]
#    id      V1 V2
# 1:  a M,F,M,F 10
# 2:  b F,M,F,M 11
# 3:  c M,F,M,F 12
```

(we can of course name the columns whatever you'd like)

As to timing, here's `list` vs. `paste` in `data.table` vs. `paste` in `dplyr`, we see `dplyr` is dominated on a data set of nontrivial size:

```
set.seed(102349)
NN <- 1e6
DT <- data.table(id = sample(c("a","b","c"), NN, TRUE),
                 sex = sample(c("M","F"), NN, TRUE),
                 score = sample(12, NN, TRUE))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(times = 1000L,
               mikec = DT[ , .(list(unique(sex)), max(score)), by = id],
               mikec_str = DT[ , .(paste(unique(sex), collapse = ","),
                                   score = max(score)), by = id],
               count = DT %>% group_by(id) %>% 
                 summarise(score = max(score), 
                           sex = paste(unique(sex),collapse=",")))
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#      mikec 20.31309 20.73779 30.47556 21.95649 35.02822 241.6299  1000  a 
#  mikec_str 20.34941 20.76544 32.05443 22.40155 35.32093 325.3754  1000  a 
#      count 27.20780 29.11735 47.38582 42.93207 44.54086 334.8008  1000   b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(score = max(score), sex = paste(unique(sex),collapse=","))
```

Comment: I would but the data.table option is significantly faster which is crucial in my case.

Comment: Are you sure the `data.table` solution is faster? Given your example the `dplyr` solution is faster by a factor of 10 on my machine.